# Call Servlets get method from URL bar

Tags: java, url, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to call servlets class using URL but it's not getting called.

servlets class init method is getting executed but not get method.
please find below servlet class code example.

I want to call servlets class by URL like http://localhost:8090/myApp/downloadDoc?id=1

while inspecting request in the network, it's giving 302 in response like Request

```
URL: http://localhost:8090/myApp/downloadDoc
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 
Remote Address: [::1]:8090
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

---

```
@WebServlet("/downloadDoc") 
public class FileDownloadServlet extends HttpServlet{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //@Inject
    private FileUploadService fileUploadService;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
        System.out.println("==================test============");
    }

    //@Override
     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException
                {
        System.out.println("==================do get============");
    String id = request.getParameter("id");

    // Find this file id in database to get file name, and file type
    FileDetails fileDetails = fileUploadService.findFileById(Integer.parseInt(id));

    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    ServletContext context = getServletConfig().
            getServletContext();
   // String mimetype = context.getMimeType(fileDetails.getFilePath());

    if(fileDetails!= null) {

        // You must tell the browser the file type you are going to send
        // for example application/pdf, text/plain, text/html, image/jpg
        response.setContentType(fileDetails.getFileType());
        // Make sure to show the download dialog
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=\""+fileDetails.getFileName()+"\"");

        // Assume file name is retrieved from database
        // For example D:\\file\\test.pdf

        File my_file = new File(fileDetails.getFilePath());

        // This should send the file to browser
      //  OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(my_file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
           out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
    }
    }
   // @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("====================service");

    }

    //@Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("======================doPost");
    }

   // @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("==================Destroy servlet");
    }

    }
```

Comment: when calling `fileUploadService.findFileById` it will throw a NPE as it has not been initialized

Comment: @ScaryWombat right but here point is to for NPE method should execute. here call didn't reach to the method itself.